# Efficiently reorganize binary data then transpose chunk

Tags: python, binary, bitstring

I have a raw binary file that holds 32 samples and each sample is 256 bits. The nth element of each sample combine to create a single valid sample so in this case 256 valid samples. The sample order is incorrect on the input file and must be reordered. To do that I am using the bitstring module and reading in 8192 bits then unpacking them into the correct order. This seams reasonable. Now I must combine the nth bit from all samples into a new structure so that each sample is 32 bits. I'm asking how to efficiently reorder (accomplished) and then transpose raw binary data. Maybe it would be better to abandon the bitstring module entirely.

```
from bitstring import ConstBitStream, ReadError, BitArray
ch = [ConstBitStream('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
                      for i in range(32)]
test = "test"

fp = ConstBitStream(filename="test.jlb")

try:
    firstChunk = fp.read(8192)#read one sample    
    ch[28],ch[29],ch[17],ch[18],ch[19],ch[11],ch[14],ch[12],\
    ch[31],ch[23],ch[13],ch[21],ch[20],ch[7],ch[24],ch[9],\
    ch[8],ch[27],ch[10],ch[30],ch[22],nocare,nocare,ch[6],\
    ch[4],ch[5],ch[3],ch[2],ch[1],ch[15],ch[0],nocare = firstChunk.unpack('32*bits:256')#put it in order
except ReadError:
    pass
blist = [element[3] for element in ch]#try to create new sample
print(blist)#looks good list of booleans
print(BitArray('').join(blist))#no good 0x00
```

Comment: To clarify, you are asking how to read the n-th column of the 32 x 256 bit matrix?

Comment: Sorry it gets confusing. I'm really asking to just transpose raw binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct `blist` you get list of booleans, which in Python are just integers (False == 0, True == 1).

So when you try to `join` them it is creating a new `BitArray` object from each integer type, which is interpreted as "create a `BitArray` of this length". So `BitArray(False)` is empty (length zero), while `BitArray(True)` is a single zero bit!

This is rather counter-intuitive, but can't be helped due to reasons too lengthy to go into here.

To create from a list of booleans, just do it directly instead of using join:

```
print(BitArray(blist))
```